# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, covariance

I'm trying to get the solution(W2) of a equation, which include np.cov, using python sympy.Solvers, but get a AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste your code here as text, not as an image

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In order to get a good answer, it is really helpful if you provide a [MCVE] (code and data). Please post both the code and the data as text, not as images (the search engine doesn't play well with images and we can't copy images to our text editors).

Comment: Tell us about `R_ind` and `R_port` - are they `ndarray`?  If so, what `shape` and `dtype`?

Comment: the type is pandas.core.series.Series.

Comment: It is a column of the pd.DataFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.cov` with 2 1d arrays works:

```
In [202]: np.cov(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))
Out[202]: 
array([[9.16666667, 9.16666667],
       [9.16666667, 9.16666667]])
```

But if one of the arrays is `object` dtype, I get your error:

```
In [203]: np.cov(np.arange(10),np.arange(10).astype(object))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-203-db3c70a7640d> in <module>()
----> 1 np.cov(np.arange(10),np.arange(10).astype(object))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in cov(m, y, rowvar, bias, ddof, fweights, aweights)
   2300             w *= aweights
   2301 
-> 2302     avg, w_sum = average(X, axis=1, weights=w, returned=True)
   2303     w_sum = w_sum[0]
   2304 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in average(a, axis, weights, returned)
    389 
    390     if returned:
--> 391         if scl.shape != avg.shape:
    392             scl = np.broadcast_to(scl, avg.shape).copy()
    393         return avg, scl

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: it is helpful. Thank you